# modify class loose type evaluation

Tags: python, class, methods, types

Trying to add a method to a native class, the type of this class seems to be différent in a type() event keeping the same **repr** presentation

```
>>> type([]) == list
True
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
>>> class list(list) :
...    def dummy( self) :
...       self.append( "Something")
... 
>>> type( []) == list
False
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
```

Goal is to add the method to a type (list in this sample but it was dict at first attempt with more complex method) but this new behavior is not wanted. So best will be to implement the new method on a more correct way, not having a workaround for type of.

from some reply below (but not adding method to native, just create a sub class with same name in current workspace)

```
>>> x=list([])
>>> type(x) == list
True
```

Comment: `[]` *always* creates an instance of the built-in `list` type, not whatever type happens to be bound to the name `list`. You can't override how list (or set or dict) displays work.

Comment: You also are not adding a method to the built-in `list` type; you are creating a subclass of `list` and binding it to the same *name*.

Comment: You *can't* add methods to a built-in type like you can a user-defined type.

Comment: Although there is some ways to add methods to built-in types in CPython at present, it belongs to the dark magic, and it is better not to do so in actual work.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(list) # <class 'list'>

class list(list):
    def dummy(self):
        self.append( "Something")

print(list) # <class '__main__.list'>
```

In this example list is referenced as the standard lib list until a class in main gets defined with the same name. From then on the program references this class instead of the other.

I don't think you can change native python classes. You would have to change the standard library code for that...

Comment: so in other workspace, creating just a sub part of the class. Strange that the new local class is used in the type and the original  on the other side of the _eq__. Anyway thanks for the explaination